# delegate declaration in thread constructor

Tags: c#, delegates

I ran into this code:

```
bool success = true;
Thread connectThread = new Thread(delegate() { success = TryConnectingToAnalysisServer(connectionString); });
```

I never saw this syntax for a delegate, can somebody explain it?

Comment: google => Anonymous Methods

Comment: Did you look up the documentation for the `delegate` keyword in C#?  It should discuss this syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an anonymous delegate. Instead of having to write a separate function, which is what you had to in C# version 1.0:

```
void MainMethod()
{
    bool success = true;
    Thread connectThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(thread_start));
}
void thread_start() {
    success = TryConnectingToAnalysisServer(connectionString); 
}
```

With C# 2.0 you can now write this more compactly with a anonymous method:

```
void MainMethod()
{
    bool success = true;
    Thread connectThread = new Thread(delegate() {
        success = TryConnectingToAnalysisServer(connectionString); 
    });
}
```

With C# 3.0 you can write this slightly more compactly using a lambda expression:

```
void MainMethod()
{
    bool success = true;
    Thread connectThread = new Thread(() => {
        success = TryConnectingToAnalysisServer(connectionString); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its called [`Annonymous Methods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx).
What happeneds is the compiler generates a named method for you behind the scenes with the correct signature of the delegate. So the compiler generates a method:

```
public void <__k_method()
{
   success = TryConnectingToAnalysisServer(connectionString)
}
```

I suggest you read up, and also look into [`Lambda Expressions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)